# Can't get Windows XP to boot from USB?

Tags: windows-xp, iso-image

On my Netbook I can get windows 7 to install and boot from USB, but when I download windows XP pro and install, I get stuck on a blue screen that says "Setup is starting windows". I can't seem to get past this with XP! 
I have no disk drive, so I have to boot from my 16GB USB flash. 
What could I do to get XP? Am I missing something for XP? I've tried so many different programs  none seem to work! 
Unebootin
WinToFlash
Ubuntu.. Etc

Comment: I'm not accusing you of anything, but where did this "downloaded windows XP pro" come from? If it's a pirated edition, it may have an extended set of drivers or a stripped set of drivers that is preventing you from booting the setup properly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your drive and RAM test OK, then it sounds like it may not be properly detecting the HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer) to use.

If that's what's going on then it's probably not properly detecting that the Netbook is ACPI capable.

When you try to install XP, and it gets to the point where it prompts you to push <kbd>F6</kbd> for additional drivers, hit <kbd>F5</kbd> instead.

This should produce a list of HALs for you to choose from:

- ACPI Multiprocessor PC
- ACPI Uniprocessor PC
- Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) PC
- Compaq SystemPro Multiprocessor or 100% Compatible PC
- MPS Uniprocessor PC
- MPS Multiprocessor PC
- Standard PC
- Standard PC with C-Step i486
- Other

You may have to try a couple to figure out which works, but usually "Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) PC" is the one you want.

More info on [F5 usage here](http://www.theeldergeek.com/clean_installation_of_windows_xp.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's an issue with NTDetect.com

[This should help](http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/System/System-Enhancements/WinSetupFromUSB.shtml). Also, grab this [tool](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Miscellaneous/tiny-hexer.shtml), and follow these [instructions](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/112630-0x0000007b-blue-screen-error-during-text-setup/page__p__738009#entry738009)

It may also be an issue with AHCI.  You could try following [these instructions](http://www.prime-expert.com/articles/b01/installing-windows-xp-on-netbooks-and-other-computers-without-dvd-drive.php) as well

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.